Golang runtime/internal/syscall.Syscall6 consuming large amount of CPU
I have a TCP based proxy server running on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. It performs really well but when analyzing with https://github.com/google/pprof it gives me this output:
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
     4.97s 54.98% 54.98%      4.97s 54.98%  runtime/internal/syscall.Syscall6
     0.95s 10.51% 65.49%      0.95s 10.51%  runtime.(*lfstack).pop
     0.49s  5.42% 70.91%      0.98s 10.84%  runtime.stealWork
     0.26s  2.88% 73.78%      0.26s  2.88%  runtime.(*lfstack).push
     0.25s  2.77% 76.55%      0.25s  2.77%  runtime.pMask.read (inline)
     0.23s  2.54% 79.09%      0.23s  2.54%  runtime.futex
     0.20s  2.21% 81.31%      0.20s  2.21%  runtime.(*randomEnum).next (inline)
     0.09s     1% 82.30%      0.09s     1%  runtime.nanotime (inline)
     0.08s  0.88% 83.19%      0.09s     1%  runtime.findObject
     0.07s  0.77% 83.96%      0.07s  0.77%  runtime.(*mspan).base

The majority of the time / CPU is on runtime/internal/syscall.Syscall6 when I try and find more details about this I cannot find anything on what it truly is. Here is the SVG output:

can anyone give me some more insights on what the Syscall6 is?
I can provide some psuedo code:
func main() {
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("%v:%v", config.Cfg.Server.Host, config.Cfg.Server.Port))
    if err != nil {
        logging.Logger.Error().
            Err(err).
            Msg("An unexpected error has occurred")
        return
    }

    for {
        c, err := listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            logging.Logger.Error().
                Err(err).
                Msg("An unexpected error has occurred")
            return
        }
        go handlers.Handle(c)
    }
}


It then does some simple auth checking and then it processes the request and writes back the response.
func routehttps(c net.Conn, r *http.Request) error {
    dialer := net.Dialer{}
    log.Print("Dialing HTTPS connection")
    conn, err := dialer.Dial("tcp", r.Host)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer conn.Close()

    response := &http.Response{
        Status:        "200 OK",
        StatusCode:    200,
        Proto:         "HTTP/1.1",
        ProtoMajor:    1,
        ProtoMinor:    1,
        Body:          ioutil.NopCloser(strings.NewReader("")),
        ContentLength: 0,
    }

    if err := response.Write(c); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    go io.Copy(conn, c)
    if _, err := io.Copy(c, conn); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

I cannot find any traces of the Syscall6 is this related to the TCP sockets itself?
I tried different variotions on my dialer with socket options but non made a difference.

I think from what I can see in the picture of your profile, those calls are coming via syscall.Splice, which would make sense since your program probably spends all its time copying bytes between two network connections.

Hi, yes thank you the io.Copy operation was cuasing this I used a io.CopyBuffer and this resolved my issues.

So I solved the issue via using a io.CopyBuffer
// Golang program to illustrate the usage of 
// io.CopyBuffer() function 
  
// Including main package 
package main 
  
// Importing fmt, io, os, and strings 
import ( 
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
) 
  
// Calling main 
func main() { 
  
    // Defining source 
    src := strings.NewReader("GfG\n") 
  
    // Defining destination using Stdout 
    dst := os.Stdout 
  
    // Defining buffer of length one using 
    // make keyword 
    buffer := make([]byte, 1) 
  
    // Calling CopyBuffer method with its parameters 
    bytes, err := io.CopyBuffer(dst, src, buffer) 
  
    // If error is not nil then panics 
    if err != nil { 
        panic(err) 
    } 
  
    // Prints output 
    fmt.Printf("The number of bytes are: %d\n", bytes) 
} 

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/io-copybuffer-function-in-golang-with-examples/

io.Copy is the same as io.CopyBuffer except with a default buffer size. The only thing using a 1 byte buffer could solve is to make the transfer as slow as possible (but the buffer is probably not even used in the network case due to the splicing, and this example isn't even using network connections). The calls to splice are because that is the most efficient way to copy data between network sockets, and if your program is working correctly, I would expect the profile to show most of the time in those calls.

I am reusing a sync.Pool for the buffer
 New: func() interface{} {
  return bufio.NewWriter(nil)
 },
}```

this solved the CPU spiking of me.
